# How can I check if the email and the data is valid or not

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

`I got requests and I want to validate the data`
`Here is the data I want to check`

const RouterUser= require("express").Router();
const user = require('../module/UsersSchema');

RouterUser.post('/register',async (req,res)=>{

```
//Test Validtion data


//Get Data From Clinet Side
const data = new user({
    name:req.body.name,
    email:req.body.email,
    password:req.body.password
});
//Send Data To Api
try{
    const {_id} = await data.save();
    const token = jwt.sign({_id_user:_id},process.env.tokenPass);
    res.header('uath-token',token).send(token);
}
catch(err){
    res.status(400).json({
        message:"Fuild",
        error:err
    })
}
```

})

`here my schema`
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name:{
type:String,
require,
min:6,
max:250
},
email:{
type:String,
require,
min:6,
max:250,
},
password:{
type:String,
require,
min:6,
max:1100
}
});

const User = mongoose.model("User",UserSchema);

module.exports = User`enter code here`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check by adding the package Validator

`npm install validator`

```js
    const validator = require('validator')
    
      email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: [true, 'Please provide an email'],
        validate: {
            validator: validator.isEmail,
            message: 'Please provide a valid email address'
        },
      }
```

Or using Regex

```
email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please provide an email'],
    match: [
      /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,
      'Please provide a valid email',
    ],
    unique: true,
  }
```